# Visual Studio remote Linux project compilation results in error MSB4044 despite the valid connection

Tags: linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a project (on Windows) that needs to be compiled remotely on Linux. It used to work some time ago (and address is valid, because it connects), but now I'm getting following error:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets(190,5): error MSB4044: The "ValidateValidArchitecture" task was not given a value for the required parameter "RemoteTarget".`

When I double click that error it opens `Linux.targets` file at following section:

```
<Target Name="_ValidateValidArchitecture" DependsOnTargets="_ResolveRemoteDebuggingTarget;_RequiresRemoteConnection">
    <ValidateValidArchitecture Condition="'$(ValidateArchitecture)' != 'False' and '$(RequireRemoteConnection)' == 'true'"
      Platform="$(Platform)"
      RemoteTarget="$(ResolvedRemoteDebuggingTarget)"
      FailOnInvalidArchitecture="false"
      ProjectDir="$(ProjectDir)"
      RemoteProjectDir="$(RemoteProjectDir)"
      IntermediateDir="$(IntDir)"/>
</Target>
```

I couldn't find solution in Microsoft documentation. Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem can arise if you delete remote target machine, add it again and try to build the project immediately. The solution, at least for me, was to go to Project properties -> General -> Remote Build Machine and make sure that in there is only the IP address of your Linux machine, not some random numbers.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, if I remember correctly I had to completelly delete previous uncorrect linux machine and add it once again from scratch.